# Java Convert Public and private Key to string and then back

Tags: java, sqlite, rsa

I have a private and a public RSA 2048bit keys and i have the need to convert them to String for save them in a SQLite DB but i need also a method for convert them back to private/public key when i read data in db, How i can do it in Java?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: use base64 encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Base64Encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) and [Base64Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html)

Base64 encoding/decoding is quite useful when you need to serialize binary data into String, because it produces a *good* string, it's just ascii with more or less no special character.

```
    // You can turn your bytes into a string using encoder.
    String keyAsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key);
    // ....
    ///

    // When you need your bytes back you call the decoder on the string.
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyAsString);
```

On java versions lower then 1.8 you can use [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/)

Comment: I copied ahead of time then, my post is was written 2 minute before the comment.

Comment: Well. Even then, this is still an almost link only answer. If you improve it I will for sure reverse my vote.

Comment: @GhostCat I hate when people are right, and you are right.

Comment: I would comply, but I can't figure out what is missing here. The reason why I answered to this question is that I didn't knew if a standard Base64 encode/decode method was present in Java SE. I looked for it and (lo and behold) I found that java 1.8 had it. I Always used commons [Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) . So I decided to share that.

Comment: I think this should do.

Comment: @minus Thank you. Perfect. I got my public/private key's string using below code as you suggested (for android)
String keyAsString = Base64.encodeToString(pubKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);